# Pandigital SuperNova 1080p Output?

Tags: hdmi, external-display, pandigital-supernova

I ordered a Pandigital SuperNova and I own a 1080p LED TV.

The Pandigital SuperNova has a Micro HDMI port on it. My TV has a regular HDMI port.

If I connect an HDMI cable with regular HDMI on one end to my TV with Micro HDMI on the other into my SuperNova, will I be able to have 1080p output onto my TV?

I've read from [this pcmag.com article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2394227,00.asp):

> The SuperNova plays 1080p videos, although it doesn't display them anywhere in 1080p. You get 800-by-600 on the main screen, and 720p HD on a TV, all perfectly smoothly.

But I was hoping for more confirmation on this. (actually hoping the statement to be disproven lol)

I'm not ready to accept it as a fact until more people who have tested this can reply.

Answer (score 1):

I got the tablet and YES! It does have 1080p output. :)